# Creating Account Hierarchy Page

Tags: visualforce, hierarchy

I'm trying to utilize a piece of [AppShare](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016chCEAQ) for hierarchy presentation which drops down and closes when clicked, found here:

When I run the page I'm getting the following error:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: sObject ID must be provided:
>   Same value: null  Class.AccountStructure.getObjectStructure: line 55,
>   column 1

I have tried to debug the code but based on the error:

```
public List<ObjectStructureMap> getObjectStructure(){
        asm.clear();
        if ( currentId == null ) {
            currentId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get( 'id' );
        }            
        System.assertNotEquals( currentId, null, 'sObject ID must be provided' );
        asm = formatObjectStructure( CurrentId );            
        return asm;
    }
```

as you can see that its expecting to have a currentId to be passed? and if I passed the Account.Id like this:

```
https://xxxx.visual.force.com/apex/AccountHierarchyPage?id=00141000009mTavAAE
```

Then I able to see the hierarchy for the specific Id that I'm passing, but what I want is display all the parent records from account.

What is that I need to tweak the github code?

```
<apex:page standardController="account" tabStyle="Account" > 
    <div style="height: 200px" class="bodyDiv" onclick="resizeFrame();">
        <c:AccountHierarchyTree current_Id="{!account.id}" />
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: same on github: https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/Inline-Account-Hierarchy/blob/master/src/pages/AccountHierarchyPage.page

Comment: Assertions in production code, ignorance of `StandardController` functionality...bad signs.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed your comment

Comment: As I remember correctly - it was showing the parent and grand parent for the record with all siblings - isn't it what you want? The page is supposed to be embed into Account's page layout.

Comment: @Oleksiy:  yes I have tried your suggestion and the page is embed into accounts page layout but i do not see the children for that parent, is there a way to get sample parent/child data for the account to test it out? maybe in my org i do not have any parent/children.

Comment: You can set parents for some accounts and test - it's working.

Comment: I did and see parent/child but my question still remains instead of embed  in account page if I have it in a separate page?  Goes back to my question I have originally raised.  Any input?

Comment: Here is a different solution, but it looks like code far away from perfection [Salesforce: How to create TreeView in Visualforce Page?](http://blog.biswajeetsamal.com/post/2014/08/07/salesforce-how-to-craete-treeview-in-visualforce-page/)